# What is causing uneven spacing between these buttons of mine?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out what is causing the uneven spacing that you see in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Fj5.png  (can't embed images yet ... sorry) 
[image]
which comes from http://playclassicsnake.com/Scores. My relevant CSS is

```
.page-btn { background: #19FF19; color: #FFF; border: 0; border: 3px solid transparent; }
.page-btn.cur-page { border-color: #FFF; cursor: pointer; }
.page-btn + .page-btn { margin-left: 5px; }
```

and I've inspected the elements to make sure there's nothing fishy. What's the deal?

Comment: Check that you haven't got any white-space characters or a new line between the first two `.page-btn`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a new line character in your HTML just after your first button:

```
<button class="page-btn cur-page">1</button>
<button class="page-btn">2</button><button class="page-btn">3</button>
```

Make it all in 1 line and it will start to work without any extra spaces:

```
<button class="page-btn cur-page">1</button><button class="page-btn">2</button><button class="page-btn">3</button>
```

Your CSS is perfectly fine and doesn't need to be altered as mentioned by others..

Comment: I didn't know that new line characters affected anything

Answer (score 0):

**Hi now try to this css**

```
#page-btns-holder {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-size: 0;
}
div#page-btns-holder * {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.page-btn {
    background: #19FF19;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 0;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Define your `btn` `display inline-block` and remove space to `inline-block` `element` define your patent `font-size:0;` and child define `font-size:14px;` as like this i give you example

**[Remove Whitespace Between Inline-Block Elements](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)**

Answer (score -1):

Try to make the font-size of the parent content 0, also try setting letter-spacing to 0.